# Comparing variables in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication, django-users

I want to compare a variable in django template. Problem is as follows.
I am loading a set of photos in a page. When a template is loaded, it contains all the photos. But when a user clicks on edit button, i want that only properties of photos saved by that user should be in editable mode.

In my template i have following

```
  {% for img in images.object_list %}
<!-- EDIT VIEW  -->
                {% if view == "edit" %} 
                   {% if user_id_log == img.image.name %} 
                      <<Load Photos if user id matches with logged in user>>
                   {% else %}
                      <<Skip that photo>>
```

Last line written above is not working.

user_id_log -- User id of logged in user. Passing it from a view in render_to_response method

img.image.name -- Contains user id who created that photo.

images.object_list is list of image objects.

Please let me know how can i accomplish this

Added

I am passing user_id_log as int after typecasting it in view.py Also, img.name is also int in Database

Views.py

```
def album(request, pk, view="thumbnails"):

num_images = 30
if view == "full": num_images = 10
album = Album.objects.get(pk=pk)

images = album.image_set.all()
user_id = int(request.user.id)

# add list of tags as string and list of album names to each image object
for img in images.object_list:
    tags = [x[1] for x in img.tags.values_list()]
    img.tag_lst = join(tags, ', ')
    img.album_lst = [x[1] for x in img.albums.values_list()]

d = dict(user_id_log=user_id,album=album, images=images, user=request.user, view=view, 
albums=Album.objects.all(), 
backurl=request.META["HTTP_REFERER"],media_url=MEDIA_URL)
d.update(csrf(request))
return render_to_response("photo/album.html", d)
```

Comment: Try to print `{{user_id_log}}` and `{{img.image.name}}` from template and show us the output.

Comment: It could be a typo, if thinking about it logically it perhaps should be `img.name` instead of `img.image.name`.

Comment: @Rohan - 
    {{user_id_log}} -- 1  (Which is correct user id)


    {{img.name}} --  2   (Which is correct user id)

Comment: @limelights - U were correct. It was typo... 
How can i compare them?

Comment: `{% if user_id_log == img.name %}` or `{% ifequal user_id_log img.name %}{% endifequal %}`

Comment: @limelights Tried both option. Does not work. Always goes to else condition

Comment: I am passing user_id as int after typecasting it in view.py
Also, img.name is also int in Database

Comment: is it `user_id` or `user_log_id`?

Comment: @limelights I m sorry. Its user_id_log

Comment: Allright, well as you said if `user_log_id` is `1` and `img.name` is `2` then that would make perfect sense why you end up in the else.

Comment: @limelights -- But there is for loop in which i am comparing it. There are 4 images. img.name for first 2 images is 2 but for other 2 is 1. So for atleast last 2 images it should satisfy if condition

Comment: There must be something else manipulating your objects. The comparisons are correctly done.

Comment: @limelights - Yes, even i think so. DO u have any idea in which we can debug/check what is going wrong. I have been trying this from past 3-4 hrs :(

Comment: Could you post your view?

Comment: @limelights - Updated above